# What does "Do" mean in the birthplace field of the 1850 US Census?

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, census-records

I am reviewing a 1850 Census Image for Western Pennsylvania, and under place of birth I see both what looks like a "Pa" and a "Do". I know some of the individuals marked "Do" were born in Pennsylvania, but why is there a difference as the penmanship looks to be the same individual in both of the following examples. There is also some "Do" marks in the occupation column.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do is short for Ditto which means that it is the same as the line above.